# RDS Access Denied in ECS Fargate through Secret Manager

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-secrets-manager

I am facing an issue with my Laravel application deployment on AWS ECS. The deployment process involves Jenkins, AWS ECR, and ECS. The new task is created, but there's an "Access Denied" error connecting to the RDS database.

I have provided my deployment files for reference.

JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="794664785634"
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
        IMAGE_REPO_NAME="product-mangement"
        IMAGE_TAG="${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        REPOSITORY_URI = "794664785634.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/product-mangement"
        ECS_CLUSTER = "product-mangement"
        ECS_SERVICE = "product-mangement"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout Latest Source') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master',
                url: 'https://github.com/jhon-123/product-mangement',
                credentialsId: 'jenkins_pta'
            }
        }
        stage('Logging into AWS ECR') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com"""
                }
                 
            }
        }
        
        // Building Docker images
        stage('Building image') {
            steps{
                script {
                    dockerImage = docker.build "${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
                }
            }
        }
   
        // Uploading Docker images into AWS ECR
        stage('Pushing to ECR') {
            steps{  
                script {
                    sh """docker tag ${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} ${REPOSITORY_URI}:$IMAGE_TAG"""
                    sh """docker push ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"""
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy to ECS') {
            steps {
                sh "aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ECS_CLUSTER} --service ${ECS_SERVICE} --force-new-deployment"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official PHP image as a base
FROM php:8.1-fpm

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

USER root

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
# RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
# RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
  # chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy the project files into the container
COPY . /var/www

# Copy .env.example to .env
COPY .env.prod .env

# Install Composer dependencies
RUN composer install

# Cache configuration
RUN php artisan config:clear
RUN php artisan config:cache

# Generate Laravel application key
RUN php artisan key:generate

# Copy the start script into the container
COPY script.sh /var/www/script.sh

# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /var/www/script.sh

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# show message
RUN echo "ehllo"

# Run the start script as the CMD
CMD ["/var/www/script.sh"]
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Run Laravel migrations
php artisan migrate

# Seed Database
php artisan db:seed
echo "seeded successfully"

# Start the Laravel application
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Problem: The new task is created, but there is an "Access Denied" error connecting to the RDS database. The .env.prod file contains the correct RDS connection details.

.env.prod:  => i have copied .env.prod file into .env in Dockerfile and also i did check on live ECS Task it is there but ECS is not getting Credential from secret manager. i'm very confused

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=prod
APP_KEY=base64:LyxaydSCa8HIgUdaLLQCPehtSK2siVr0o+bT6jcXWmM=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=product-management.c7ebhtqyydqk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=product-management
#DB_USERNAME=laravel
#DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Question:

What could be causing the "Access Denied" error in the deployment process, and how can I resolve it? Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

First i was doing deployment in custom VPC but i thought could be issue with VPC and may be i was not able to give proper security group and subnets so i tried with default but got same error.

i have tried RDS with RDS connection through Secret manager and in Task Definition i have added these permission as a Task role within the Role

```
AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole
AmazonECS_FullAccess
AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
AmazonRDSDataFullAccess
AmazonRDSFullAccess
```

I have created an RDS instance and saved the username and password into the Secret Manager. I have used Secret Manager keys into ECS Task Definition in Environment variable as ValueFrom like this

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:794664117291:secret:product-management-secrets-83qahw::username:
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:794664117291:secret:product-management-secrets-83qahw::password:
```

and Engine, Host, and Port I have added in .env.example file that I'm copying into Dockerfile.

I have also checked with SSH into ECS Task and did check that the .env.example is copying into .env but the issue is that ECS is not getting the secret manager environment variable and due to that coming Access Denied issue and ECS getting default database forge from config/database.php

Comment: I don't understand why you mention Secrets Manager, and why you say your task should be getting the secrets from secrets manager. There is nothing in any of the code or configuration you have shown that would interact with Secrets Manager at all. Did you define the secrets in your ECS Task definition? If so, add the task definition to your question. Also, you haven't provided Secrets Manager permissions to your ECS task role yet.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB for replying to me. Yes, i have added secret manager variables in Task Definition that i made for RDS.

and i have also added permission to ECS  Task role, i have added in my question can you please see above in my question

Comment: please let me know if you still have confusion, i will explain more

Comment: @MarkB when i do ``SSH`` into ``ECS TASK`` and run command ``php artisan migrate`` then also get Access denied error `` SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'172.31.95.237' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = product-management and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') `` But when i clear cache with this command ``php artisan config:cache`` and run again ``php artisan migrate`` then migrated successfully. but on new task again come same issue. i'm very confused about that why that is happending.

Comment: I'm sorry but you didn't add those details to your question. Your question still shows the original content with no edits. Your question still shows **zero** information about your use of Secrets Manager.

Comment: Dear, i have added Role permission for Task Role in the last of question.

Comment: @MarkB, i have added little more information regarding secret manager that i have added in ECS Task Definition as an Environment Variables.
and please can you tell me what type of information you required about ECS. Thanks

Comment: I assume you have those secrets set to the environment variables `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD`? Did you check if those environment variables are actually present inside the ECS container, and that they have the correct values?

Comment: Yes, Environement variables are present in ECS Container and these values.
can you please check this picture that i have attached
[Environment Variables inside ECS container](https://imgur.com/rjEM9tU)

Comment: That shows what ARN they are pulling the values from. When you SSH into the task, and run `echo $DB_PASSWORD` and `echo $DB_USERNAME` what does it actually show?

Comment: @MarkB i did ssh and run ``echo $DB_PASSWORD`` and ``echo $DB_USERNAME`` values are coming  [Secret Manager values in Container](https://imgur.com/EHtWzQP)

Comment: OK so this is purely a problem with your PHP app not actually picking up and using those environment variables. It doesn't appear to be a problem with AWS/ECS/SecretsManager/RDS at all.

Comment: @MarkB i have tried a lot but didn't get any solution i have added logs in my Laravel application and i did check on Service Created Task ``IP`` then getting this in logs [laravel logs screenshot](https://imgur.com/HHcJnI7) and also getting same issue in Task logs.

Comment: I think you should probably post another question, with the `php` and `laravel` tags to get attention from people who know those technologies, and focus on the fact that the environment variable values are not being used in the database connection. I personally have no idea if Laravel is even supposed to load those environment variables at all, if a `.env` file is present.

Comment: Okay Dear @MarkB for helping to me. a lot of thanks to assist me.

Comment: @MarkB, i have posted another question regarding this issue with ``PHP``, ``Laravel`` and ``AWS`` tag [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77489807/environment-variable-values-are-not-being-used-in-the-database-connection)